# Connect to a ipaddress programmatically to get the return value

Tags: android

I need to call a ip address say http://12.12.1.43:8080/xyzzz , this will return me a XML. But i am not sure how can i call this from android programmatically.
The server i am trying to access is remotely.

Answer (score 2):

you need to parse the XML response received from the server like this

```
String uri = "http://12.12.1.43:8080/xyzzz ";

URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection connection =
    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(xml);
```

Comment: My main question is from where to call this in activity class? and this require any setting

Comment: you need to run this inside a service.
no special settings are required .

Comment: any link please i am completely blank with this

Comment: I am using emulator so will this http connection works on emulator to test or it requires a device with internet .

Comment: read this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/).
This will work on emulator if you have internet connection on your machine

Comment: Hey the example shared in link is not working for me,can you please help me out

Comment: HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); error for this httppost has url ,trying from emulator,not sure if it works i emulator without any setting